# Strange nav element code not visibile in the page source

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, nav

Hi i am trying to collect all the links in this page: https://www.biblico.it/index.html using selenium and jsoup.
My problem is that i cannot collect the links in the nav menu.
For example `<a href="authorities.html">Authorities</a>` and `<a href="#">Who&nbsp;we&nbsp;are</a>` are not present in the page source but i can see their code using the "inspect element" method in chromium.

I understand that they are generated on the fly in some strange way, but i don't know how to collect them. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Jsoup is unable to work with elements that are generated on the fly by some script and on the fly generated elements are never displayed using "View page source" option in any browser. On the other hand "inspect element" function in chrome can display code of these on the fly generated elements. I have found that the method WebElement.GetAttribute() works actually like the "inspect element" function in chrome and it resolves my problem.
So the java code to grab all the links in https://www.biblico.it/index.html is:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        try{
            driver.get("https://www.biblico.it/index.html");
     List<WebElement> links = ((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementsByTagName("a");
            for(WebElement link: links) {
                if (link != null) {
                    String text = link.getAttribute("innerHTML");
                    String href = link.getAttribute("href");

                    System.out.println(text+" "+href);
                }
            }
            driver.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A friend and I were having this problem too yesterday. He install a chrome extension which allows you to view the relative Xml path, and absolute paths for a given element on a page. You can then use selenium to find it by xpath.

Sorry if this is lacking more information, but it should be enough to get you somewhere.

Comment: Can you explain a bit, i have downloaded XPath Helper extension and it is giving me this "xpath" https://pastebin.com/UcpEWXmu for the link <a href="authorities.html">Authorities</a>. I used driver.findElementByXPath(String xpath)  to find the element and display its text but it did not work D:

Comment: By the way what you suggested works only for the elements that are actually present in the page source. It is not working only for the elements inside the nav.